# print coulmn name in saved csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I want to know that how much null values exist in every column of my data. As my data is too large I am saving the result in csv to get a clear picture. But the problem is in my csv, I am unable to see the column name. What should i do to to print the column name against the sum of null values in my CSV file?

```
  aw= data.isnull().sum()
  aw.to_csv (r'C:/Users/a.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

my CSV file looks like this
0
0
0
10
0
9

I want to see it like this

> feature1     0  feature2     0  feature3     0  feature4     11
> feature5     12  feature6     12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the resulting aw is not a DataFrame. To check `type(aw)` output `pandas.core.series.Series`

what you could try is

```
aw = pd.DataFrame(data.isnull().sum()).T
```

the output is

```
    feature1    feature2    feature3
0   0           0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('a.csv', sep=' ', header=None)
data.columns = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']
print(data)

   feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4  feature5  feature6
0         0         0         0        10         0         9
```